# How do I 'narrow' down to a specific EJB when there are multiple EJB's

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have the following situation:

Two EJB's implementing the same interface

```
@Stateless(name="theOne")
public class EjbOne implements InterfaceOne {
    ...
}

@Stateless(name="theSecond")
public class EjbTwo implements InterfaceOne {
    ...
}
```

I want to inject a specific EJB into a third class

```
@Stateless
public class EjbThree  {
    @EJB(...???...mappedName="theOne"? name=...? )
    private EjbOne ejbOne;
}
```

How should I do this?
(Mind, I'm using @EJB, not @Inject with a @Qualifier)

Comment: Typo I think, in the third class you're probably using InterfaceOne, not EjbOne.

Comment: @Gimby either would be fine... The idea is that I get an instance of EjbOne

Comment: You're already doing that. `private EjbOne ejbOne;` By specifically using the EjbOne object type, it can't be anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing concrete class `private EjbOne ejbOne;` There is no alternative. You are not using interface at all instead you should reference like this if you want use good old polymorphism  `@EJB private InterfaceOne ejbOne` then your question will make sense, what you can do is:

a. `@EJB(beanName="EjbOne") private InterfaceOne ejbOne`

b. `@EJB(lookup ="jndi-address") private InterfaceOne ejbOne`

c. `@EJB(mappedName="vendor-specific-address") private InterfaceOne ejbOne`

d. `@EJB(name="java:comp/env like logical name") private InterfaceOne ejbOne`

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html